# What is the maximum URI length in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, get, uri

I'm wandering what the maximum URI length is in codeigniter, and if URI segments being used as arguments to a controller function count towards the browsers GET length limit? I think most browsers cap there GET parameter length to about 2000?

Currently if my total URI length (inc. https://domain/folder/controller/function/argument) exceeds around 1560 characters I get a forbidden message.

'Forbidden You don't have permission to access /folder/controller/function/argument on this server'

If I trim the characters back to under around 1550~1560 it works fine again. I realise 1500+ is alot anyway, which is why I was wandering if URI counts towards the GET limit.

Has anyone experienced this problem? Is there a solution aside from POSTing all data?

BTW: I'm using the URI protocol AUTO in the config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember the whole URI is limited to a more or less specific length. Something is already mentioned here: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)

However, it feels a little bit curious, that you require such long uris. If you append a query string of around 1000 characters length, thats already 1kB of data. In my oppinion a query string is not the right place to transport data around.

Comment: I agree, it just seems to be less than I thought, especially with codeigniter. I will just need to wrap the information in a form and post it through

Comment: I have moved to a POST based solution - it just means that a lot of things are wrapped up as buttons. Cheers